# multi label problem with intermediate labels

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

I am trying to create a model for the following problem

```
id   input (diagnoses)    elapsed_days    output (medication)
 1     [2,3,4]                 0             [3,4]
 1     [4,5,6]                 7             [1]
 1     [2,3]                  56             [6,3]
 2     [6,5,9,10]              0             [5,3,1]
```

Rather than a single label for the different codes over time, there are labels at each time period.
I am think that my arch would be  [input] -> [embedding for diagnoses] -> [append normalized elapsed days to embeddings]
-> [LSTM] -> [FFNs] -> [labels over time]

I am familiar with how to set this up if there were a single label per id.  Given there are labels for each row (i.e. multiple per id), should I be passing the hidden layers of the LSTM through the FFN and then assigning the labels?  I would really appreciate if somebody could point me to a reference/blog/github/anything for this kind of problem or suggest an alternative approach here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `[6,3]` is equal to `[3, 6]`.

You can use Sigmoid activation with Binary Cross-Entropy loss function (`nn.BCELoss` class) instead of Softmax Cross-Entropy (`nn.CrossEntropyLoss` class).

But the output ground truth instead of integers like when using `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`. You need to make them sort of one hot encoding instead. For example, if the desired output is `[6, 3]` and the output has 10 nodes. The `y_true` has to be `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`.

Depending on how you implement your data generator, this is one way to do it.

```
output = [3, 6]
out_tensor = torch.zeros(10)
out_tensor[output] = 1
```

But if `[6,3]` is not equal to `[3, 6]`. Then more information about this is needed.

Comment: Right I realize that.  My question was if I just passed each record in, the DL model would not know that row 1 & row 2 belong to the same person.  How do I ensure that?

Comment: I see. The only way I can think of is stacking them together. If the input numbers aren't duplicate then it can become one hot like output as well.

Comment: For example the first person will have (3, 10) both input and output shape

Comment: Actually maybe (10, 3) for pytorch.